# Class App\Http\Controllers\Community/CommunityContoller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

**Code:**

```
Route::resource('community','Community/CommunityContoller');
```

**Error:**

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Community/CommunityContoller does not exist

NOTE: There are resource controllers, communities in the Community folder, and this error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it once:

```
Route::resource('community','Community\CommunityContoller');
```

Comment: this result ... Class App\Http\Controllers\Community\CommunityContoller does not exist

Comment: Have you re-checked the Controller naming?

Comment: Please check your namespace of CommunityContoller and run `composer dump-autoload`